# how to add missing module tokenizer in list of php -m in Synology DSM 7

Tags: php, composer-php, synology

how can I get the module tokenizer available in de default php -m list of modules?

Do I need to reconfigure somewhere in Synology NAS. Or through (putty) command line in the /var/services/web/?

Comment: What version are you currently using? `php -v`

Comment: I am not sure what you are talking about because you can't enable Tokenizer. You can disable it though when compiling PHP from source. What do you mean you need it for composer?

Comment: `pmluijkx@NAS:/usr/local/bin$ php -m` this looks like you are using the wrong version. For PHP 7.3 you should use `php73`

Comment: I provided an answer to your question by guessing at your problem, but your question isn't very clear so if I was wrong let me know.

Comment: I am using version pmluijkx@NAS:~$ php -v
PHP 7.3.3 (cli) (built: Dec 18 2020 10:30:19) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2018 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.3.3, Copyright (c) 1998-2018 Zend Technologies

Comment: I need composer to install an app.    Problem 1
    - nikic/php-parser[v4.6.0, ..., v4.13.2] require ext-tokenizer * -> it is missing from your system. Install or enable PHP's tokenizer extension.

Comment: Execute composer with `php73` and it should work.

Comment: how do I execute composer with php73 // php73 composer install doesn't work

Comment: Just Google how to run composer with different PHP. It's as simple as `php73 pathToComposer`